# Cannot display special characters from mysql database using Codeigniter ..Display &quot;Description&quot;

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

- The insert/update is successful but it is appearing in the table as:
- For example  the characters "Description" are displayed not properly.
- the database and it's tables are utf8_general_ci

  **Controller:**

  ```
  function add()
  {           
      if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
      {                   

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('question', 'question', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer', 'answer', 'required');
      $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><em class="error">', '</em>');

      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // valf_idation hasn't been passed
      {

      }
      else // passed valf_idation proceed to post success logic
      {

      $form_data = array(
          'question' => set_value('question'),
          'answer' => set_value('answer')

          if ($this->Faq_model->setClientData($form_data) == TRUE) 
          {
              $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Client Saved Successfully');
              $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_type', 'success');
          }
          else
          {
              $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'Oops Error Occured While Saving Client');   
              $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_type', 'error');   
          }
              redirect('admin/faq');
          }
          }

      $data['main_content'] = 'admin/faq/add';
      $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
  }
  ```

Comment: It's really not clear what the problem is here. Is "Description" in your data?

Answer (score 0):

When you are showing the description just use `html_entity_decode();`  function to show it. I think it will works what you want.

Reference: [html_entity_decode()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp)

Comment: display data in database(Mysql) this format : &quot;hello&quot;&quot;hiiiiiiiiiiiii&quot;